# google analytics отключить на определенной странице

Tags: google-analytics

Не понимаю как его отключить, что-бы скрипт не прикреплялся на странице

Comment: просто взять и не добавлять на данную странницу.

Comment: Согласен с вышесказанным: что тебе мешает не добавлять его на ту или иную страницу?

Comment: может, вам нужен [adblock plus](https://adblockplus.org/)?

Comment: В том то и дело что его туда не добаляли, он просто автоматом туда прикрепляется